# Gerar PDF e anexar para enviar o email c#

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, .net-core

Boa tarde pessoal, eu tenho um modal, aonde o usuário pode enviar um email, neste modal, eu carreguei um `HTML`, para que eu consiga gerar o PDF e anexar para enviar no email.
Porém vi vários artigos na internet, e estou até um pouco confusa, em qual linha de raciocínio devo seguir.

Segue na API como está o envio do email:

```
 [HttpPut]
    [Route("sendEmail")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = WriteBudgetPolicy.Name)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail(EmailProposalsViewModel obj)
    {
        var company = _companyAppService.GetUnique(obj.CompanyId);
        var result = new ReturnViewModel { Model = company };
        try
        {

            await Util.SendEmailProposalsAsync(obj.Email, company.Email, company.Password, company.Port.Value, company.Server, obj.Message, obj.Subject, company.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Errors = new Error { Key = "SendEmail", Value = ex.Message };
        }
        return ApplicationResult(result);
    }


  public static Task SendEmailProposalsAsync(string destinatario, string remetente, string password, int port, string host, string message, string subject, string displayName)
    {

        var msg = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(remetente, displayName),
            To = { destinatario },
            Subject = subject,
            Body = message,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
        };

        var smtpCliente = new SmtpClient(host, port);
        smtpCliente.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(remetente, password);
        smtpCliente.Credentials = credentials;
        smtpCliente.EnableSsl = false;
        if (host == "gmail.com")
        {
            smtpCliente.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpCliente.EnableSsl = true;
        }

        if (host == "yahoo.com.br")
        {
            smtpCliente.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.br";
        }

        if (host == "hotmail.com")
        {
            smtpCliente.Host = "smtp.live.com";
            smtpCliente.EnableSsl = true;
        }

        if (host == "live.com")
        {
            smtpCliente.Host = "smtp.live.com";
            smtpCliente.EnableSsl = true;
        }

        smtpCliente.Send(msg);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

O `front-end` é em angular, seria possível gerar o PDF e enviar por email, sem ser necessário salvar(que seria o ideal) ?
Utilizdo `.net core`

Comment: Você pode gerar ele no front end e postar para o backend e enviar, gerar e enviar no backend, ter um template e alterar os valores antes de enviar... São várias abordagens diferentes e dependem muito do seu cenário e necessidade.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a minha necessidade, seria aproveitar o do front, pois eu já tenho todo um HTML pronto, apenas queria gerar ele em PDF no caso, se fosse possível apenas salvar temporiaramente, e depois enviar como anexo no email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O front-end é uma camada de apresentação. Como o próprio nome já diz, deve ser usada (somente) para apresentação. Como nada que venha do front-end é confiável, por mais que se tenha qualquer lógica no mesmo ela deverá ser repetida/validada no backend.

Transpondo para o seu caso, um "simples" PDF para ser anexado em um e-mail, caso feito no front-end, está passível de alterações por parte do usuário.

Dado esse pequeno prefácio, NÃO gere o seu pdf no front-end. Ele até poderia ser "emulado" para ter uma apresentação mais elegante para os seus usuários, entretanto, deveria ser gerado, mesmo que em memória, no back-end.

É possível gerar um PDF com .net core? Sim, jogando rapidamente no google você deverá encontrar uma dezena de opções, pagas, gratuitas, open source, à gosto. [Pesquisando por "PDF" no nuget.org você encontra mais de 2 MIL resultados.](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pdf)

Quanto ao código apresentado...

Para uma ação `SendEmail`, não me parece razoável o uso do verbo `PUT`. O `POST` seria mais amplamente aplicado neste caso.

Apesar de ser uma tarefa um tanto quanto controversa, procure dar nomes com algum significado às suas variáveis. `obj` não é muito sugestivo para saber do que se trata.

Fazer o envio de e-mail "dentro" de um pedido http é algo questionável. O envio de e-mail pode ser demorado e deveria ser feito em background. Dependendo do caso, para evitar excesso de complexidade, "pode-se" fazer o envio em meio ao request.

Independentemente de fazer ou não o envio do e-mail de maneira "síncrona", o mesmo não deveria "nunca" ser feito em um controller. Dever-se-ia ter uma camada de serviço responsável por isso.

Por fim, o envio de e-mails deveria ser feito por meio de um serviço de envio de e-mails transacionais. Muitos dos provedores "tradicionais" como gmail estão bloqueando o uso de smtp com usuário e senha. Quando permitido, inclusive, são usadas "senhas" específicas para esse uso. Em alternativa, o OAuth deveria ser utilizado.

Comment: Obrigado @tvdias, no caso ele não está no controller, foi separado, mas na hora de inserir a pergunta ficou tudo junto. E referente a variável `obj` eu ainda estou fazendo os testes, então era só pra conferir se os parametros estão sendo passados corretamente. Referente ao PDF, eu preciso de algo realmente amigável para o usuário, ainda estou procurando gerar pelo próprio front, já que já tenho o template pronto do PDF.

Comment: @Mariana, se vc tem o template do PDF, carrega e preenche o template no backend. Caso contrário, o sistema sempre estará mais suscetível a ser explorado no frontend.

Comment: Ser "amigável" ou não é independente do PDF ser ou não gerado no frontend.

Comment: Ah sim, eu gero ele em uma div, com o preenchimento todo necessário, tem alguma forma pra me indicar de gerar ele na API ? Eu não preciso necessariamente salvar, preciso enviá-lo por email, pode ser salvo na memória, algo do tipo!!

Comment: Isso que eu estou pensando, o front, me gera o arquivo html, todo correto!! @tvdias, ai estou procurando uma forma de passar para a API

Comment: Ainda assim, se o front gerar o HTML ele pode ser alterado ao chamar o backend.

Comment: no front eu tenho a configuração toda, onde já aplica o CSS, eu não consigo aproveitar isso ?

Comment: Consegues, sempre vai depender do que vc tem e como faz, mas em geral não se envia "uma página" por email e mesmo que seja necessário, vc pode colocar o teu backend a fazer o pedido ao site, recuperando o HTML deste pedido

Comment: Eu não quero enviar a página por email, eu gostaria de pegar esta página, gerar o pdf dela, e ai sim enviar por email.

Comment: e pq não no backend? onde seria mais difícil de ser explorado?

Comment: Nao tem problema ser pelo back-end, mas qual ferramenta devo seguir para isso ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-5.0